# Pass Null value for Date SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pass a Null value for Data in SQL Server, but I keep getting a value of '1900-01-01'

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table (Data_Col) VALUES ('Null')"
```

How do I get a Null value instead of this value '1900-01-01'?

Edit:
 This gives an error

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Ex_Tbl (Data_1, Data_2, Date_1, Date_2, Data_3)
            VALUES (1,2,'2015-3-2',,30)"
```

But this does not

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Ex_Tbl (Data_1, Data_2, Date_1, Date_2, Data_3)
           VALUES (1,2,'2015-3-2','',30)"
```

Edit No.2
Do I need to make the string look like this.

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Ex_Tbl (Data_1, Data_2, Date_1, Date_2, Data_3)
           VALUES (1,2,'2015-3-2',Null,30)"
```

If so, I am going to need code like this correct,

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Ex_Tbl (Data_1, Data_2, Date_1, Date_2, Data_3) 
           VALUES (1,2,'2015-3-2'," & "Null" & ",30)"
```

Comment: You're still not doing what the answer suggests. Put `,NULL,` in where you currently have `,,`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I did that in the code, but I ended with a value like this, VALUES (1,2,'2015-3-2','',30). Check my edit in the OP. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You haven't mentioned a host language, which is obviously (from your examples) involved also - you're mangling strings together to try to achieve a result. You should be looking into whether *parameters* are supported which allows you to separate the query text (which you can then write once) from *data* that you want to supply. Frequently, once you switch to using parameters, it's far *easier* to deal with nullable data. (Not to mention that, unlike string mangling, you'll be safe from SQL injection)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Really, I had no idea I was mangling the strings, I thought this was the way it needed to be done? As for language, it is done in VBA. And I am pretty new to all this (This is my first time using SQL Server), what is SQL injection. Thanks for the help thus far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table (Data_Col) VALUES (NULL)"`

Null in quotes counts a string = Invalid date format = changes to 1900-01-01.

Comment: Matt's right on target. This is a SQLFiddle to help OP try out this method: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15ab4/1

Comment: When I try to pass the Null value without the quotes I get an error. And I do have allow nulls selected on the table.  @zedfoxus, that seems like a great tool, how do you work it?

Comment: @JapanDave - "I get an error" - well, that error probably contains more information which may be useful to give to people who might be trying to help you.

Comment: Sorry I am not at my PC so I can't give you the error code. I can give you the string value to see if the SQL statement is correct though.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  Sorry I am not at my PC so I can't give you the error code. I can give you the string value to see if the SQL statement is correct though. This gives an error   strSQL = "INSERT INTO Ex_Tbl (Data_1, Data_2, Date_1, Date_2, Data_3) VALUES (1,2,'2015-3-2',,30)"  But this does not     strSQL = "INSERT INTO Ex_Tbl (Data_1, Data_2, Date_1, Date_2, Data_3) VALUES (1,2,'2015-3-2','',30)"

Comment: @JapanDave - If you're trying to show more code, I'd suggest you *edit* your question and put it in there. You can use tools like the `{}` code button so that the code is readable. Code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: What does this do?   `strSQL = "INSERT INTO Ex_Tbl (Data_1, Data_2, Date_1, Date_2, Data_3) VALUES (1,2,'2015-3-2',NULL,30)" `